# How to install Freetype extension on Macbook

Tags: php, freetype

I have setup localhost on my mac by following this tutorial https://websitebeaver.com/set-up-localhost-on-macos-high-sierra-apache-mysql-and-php-7-with-sslhttps

Now I am trying to setup a PHP a project but getting this error

PHP FreeType Support:   Not Found
Freetype (in GD) is required to use ttf fonts within images.

Please help me to fix.
Thanks

Comment: did you found a solution?

Comment: Hi,
I am using Laravel Valet now.